# Formula to sum amount grouped by split string

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

Hello I have following table:

[image]

I need to count total amount for each person for `t1` rows. For `t1` "Comments" will always have same format. Each person delimiter will be `", "` and for their % it will be `" - "`. I'm planning to make some wizard for this cell to ease entering persons, but not sure yet, anyway it is out of scope for this question.

So, my result table will look like:

[image]

If ArrayFormula is too complicated, then normal formula is also fine, it won't be too much rows for persons.

So far I'm able to filter rows and split persons to get range like:

```
Person1 - 50% | John - 50% |               | $100.00
Smith - 10%   | John - 10% | Person1 - 80% | $1,000.00
Smith - 100%  |            |               | $2,000.00
```

With formula:

```
={FILTER(ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(C2:C6, ", ", false)), A2:A6 = "t1"), FILTER(ARRAYFORMULA(B2:B6), A2:A6 = "t1")}
```

But stuck to proceed further

Live example:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1e3IJaiOSlkia6ce9UGgIL_sNR6FK5TOp-BNrSYwS8Lg/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use the following in cell `G2` and pull down for the rest of them

```
=SUM(QUERY({$A$2:$B$6,INDEX(IFNA(SPLIT(REGEXEXTRACT($C$2:$C$6,E2&" - \d+"),"-")))},
        "select Col4*Col2/100 where Col3 is not null "))
```

[image]

*(You can reformat the results to your likings using the top menu: `Format` > `Number` )*

---

Functions used:

- [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)
- [`INDEX`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242)
- [`IFNA`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9365944)
- [`REGEXEXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244)
- [`SUM`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093669)
- [`SPLIT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136)

Comment: Since I needed for `t1` only, I adjusted to: `=SUM(QUERY({$A$2:$B$6,INDEX(IFNA(SPLIT(REGEXEXTRACT($C$2:$C$6,E2&" - \d+"),"-")))},
        "select Col4*Col2/100 where Col3 is not null AND Col1='t1'"))`

Comment: Great. This was not clear from your example. You can further improve the `QUERY` by using `"select Col4*Col2/100 where Col1='t1' "`. Please also choose and accept an answer so it is resolved.

Comment: Could you explain the use of `INDEX` - it should return values for specified reference, but we are not giving reference. I also replaced it with `ARRAYFORMULA` and it does the same

Comment: *"Could you explain the use of...."* When you define **no reference**, `INDEX` does function as the `ARRAYFORMULA`

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Here is the formula below:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B:B,ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXEXTRACT(C:C,E2&" - [0-9]+%"),E2&" - ",""),)))
```

① `REGEXEXTRACT(C:C,E2&" - [0-9]+%")` - Extract "person - percentage" like text with the specified person name.
For example, person name is Person1 and the formula result is Person1 - 50%.

② `REGEXREPLACE(①,E2&" - ",""))` - Extract the percentage only from the result of ①.
In the example above, the formula result is 50%.

③ `ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(②,))` - Generate an array of percentages corresponding to the person (Person1).

④ `SUMPRODUCT(C:C,③)` - Sumproduct the amount and percentages corresponding to the person (Person1)

Comment: Since I need this only for `t1`, I adjusted your formula to: `=SUMPRODUCT(FILTER($B$2:$B$7, $A$2:$A$7="t1"), FILTER(ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXEXTRACT($C$2:$C$7,E2&" - [0-9]+%"),E2&" - ",""))),$A$2:$A$7="t1"))`

Comment: Ah that's right! I would adjust it to =SUMPRODUCT(FILTER($B$:$B, $A:$A="t1"), FILTER(ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXEXTRACT($C:$C,E2&" - [0-9]+%"),E2&" - ",""))),$A:$A="t1")), deleting some fixings of rows from r2 to r7 in case you add more t1 from row 7 onwards :)